# Magento 2 - Cant save categories with too much products after migration

Tags: magento2, category, administration

When I try to save categories in Magento 2 Administration in *Products > Inventory Categories* the following Message appears:

> Something went wrong while saving the category

The exception.log contains the following message(stack-trace can be delivered if asked):

> main.CRITICAL: PDOException: There is no active transaction in
>   ../vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php:324

The problem does not appear with categories containing less than ~200(numbers may vary) products.

In my experience it doesn't matter if I run the system in production or developer mode. I already truncated the **url_rewrite** table, cleaned cache and reindexed after migration.

Comment: If you say the number varies, it would be odd for it to be a size problem?

Do you have an error in mysql at start up? Check your logs there.

Comment: The only warning i found there was: `[Warning] You need to use --log-bin to make --binlog-format work.`